# How to add new data point and remove leftmost data point dynamically in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am first populating 10 data points every 1 second using setInterval, after generating first 10 data points, from the 11th data point I want to start removing the 1st data point that exist, similarly when adding 12th data point I want to remove 2nd data point(or leftmost data point), so on...

I have 2 issues

1) after first 10 data points. graph lines are not seen **(check below image)**

2) consistency of having only 10 data points on screens losses slowly, I see new points are added and old points are removed but somehow slowly more points are on the graph even though if condition executes and I am adding one and removing one at a time.

[image]

## data point add or remove Flow

```
1st  (add) 
2nd  (add) 
3rd  (add) 
4th  (add) 
5th  (add) 
6th  (add) 
7th  (add) 
8th  (add) 
9th  (add) 
10th (add) 
11th (add) 1st (remove) 
12th (add) 2nd (remove)
13th (add) 3rd (remove) 
14th (add) 4th (remove)
so on... (keeping only 10 point on the screen)
```

## Mycode

**html code**

```
<canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
<input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" value="Start button" onclick="abc()">
```

**js code**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: [],        //graph X-axis labels
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Sample Data set",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [],     //graph Y-axis data points
        }
    ]
};

var i = 0;
function adddata()
{
      if(i > 10)
      { 
        myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = (Math.random() * 100);
        myLineChart.data.labels[i] = "label"+i;
        console.log("i: "+i);
        myLineChart.data.labels.splice(0,1);
        myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data.splice(0,1);
        myLineChart.update();

      }
      else{
        myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = (Math.random() * 100);
        myLineChart.data.labels[i] = "label"+i;
        console.log("i: "+i);
        myLineChart.update();
      }   
      i++;
}

function abc()
{
  setInterval(adddata,1000);
}
var option = {
  showLines: true
};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
  data:data,
  options:option
});
```

Comment: Currently it looks like you are using `myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = (Math.random() * 100);` to add a new item to the array. Does an element with the index `i` exist already in the `data` array? Shouldn't you instead use `data.push(Math.random() * 100)`?

Comment: @TotZam No data does not exist. I am creating new data not editing any existing data. I will try using data.push(Math.random() * 100)

Comment: Let me know if that solves that problem, and I'll write up a solution with some explanation. Another thing to check is that you are using the latest Chart.js version.

Comment: @TotZam Perfect, Cant believe such a thing could solve all the issues. :) I will mark your answer as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initially set up an array, the array has a specific size.

For example, an array with 3 values will look as following:

```
array[0] = value1
array[1] = value2
array[2] = value3
```

You can only assign an element to a position that already exists in the array.

For example, the following is valid:

```
array[2] = value4;
```

However, you cannot assign a value to a position that does not yet exist in the array, and is longer than the array length. The following code, therefore, will throw an index out of bounds error:

```
array[3] = value5;
```

Currently, you are trying to add a new value to your `data` array using:

```
myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = (Math.random() * 100);
```

This code assumes that the array is at least the length of `i`, which it isn't, and is therefore throwing an error.

To append a new value to the end of an array, use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control). The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of the array and also returns a new length of the array.

You code should look like the following:

```
myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
```

Comment: just remove myLineChart at the start it wont work, I dont know why. This is how I did and it works because var data so I can directly access it no need of going for myLinedChart, it might be useful when there is more than one charts : data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
        data.labels.push("label"+i);